# Why I can not INSERT with SELECT in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update my table Assembly. Can someone understand why it does not work? Why I can not INSERT into an existing table with a SELECT Statement?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Assembly;
GO

CREATE TABLE Assembly
(
    AssemblyID  INTEGER,
    Part        VARCHAR(100),
    checksum    INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (AssemblyID, Part)
);
GO

INSERT INTO Assembly (AssemblyID, Part) 
VALUES (1001, 'Bolt'), (1001, 'Screw'),
       (2002, 'Nut'), (2002, 'Washer'),
       (3003, 'Toggle'), (3003, 'Bolt');
GO

INSERT INTO Assembly (checksum)
VALUES (SELECT checksum(AssemblyID, Part) AS checksum
        FROM Assembly)

SELECT * 
FROM Assembly
```

Comment: If you check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you use one of `VALUES` **OR** `SELECT` to `INSERT` - not both!

Comment: You can use the below form :
Insert into Assembly 
SELECT * FROM Assembly

Answer (score 5):

You already have rows in that table.  So you would UPDATE instead of INSERT.

eg

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Assembly;
GO

CREATE TABLE Assembly
             (
             AssemblyID  INTEGER,
             Part        VARCHAR(100),
             checksum int, 
             PRIMARY KEY (AssemblyID, Part)
             );
GO

INSERT INTO Assembly (AssemblyID, Part) VALUES  
(1001,'Bolt'),(1001,'Screw'),(2002,'Nut'),
(2002,'Washer'),(3003,'Toggle'),(3003,'Bolt');
GO

update Assembly set checksum = checksum(AssemblyID, Part) 

SELECT * 
FROM Assembly
```

or simply make checksum a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Assembly
             (
             AssemblyID  INTEGER,
             Part        VARCHAR(100),
             checksum as checksum(AssemblyID, Part) persisted, 
             PRIMARY KEY (AssemblyID, Part)
             );
```